# coleman gas heat only furnace,

Tags: furnace

When heat comes on, furnace runs for about 8 mins then cycles off. When the heat clicks off I get a switch open code from the board. While the furnace is running I get a normal operation code. As soon as it clicks off the gas, the switch open code re-appears.     8 mins on and 2-4 off no matter where I have the therm. set.    Thanks for your help, Paul

Comment: What model # is your furnace? Have you changed the filter recently?

Comment: Does the furnace have a forced air fan or is it a gravity furnace?